# Area51 pagination having transmission problems

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, pagination

When I step forward through the Area51 proposal pages, it gets stuck, and takes about a minute of waiting get into gear.  For instance, if I successfully make it to page 6 (as indicated by the inverted page number on the bottom-right), then click next or 7, the link will be `http://area51.stackexchange.com/?page=7&tab=hot`, but I'll still be on page 6, with all the same proposals shown.

This is probably a caching issue, meaning I should probably try throwing away my cookies or clearing my browsing doohicky.  I'd rather see if someone can reproduce the issue first :-)

I'm using Firefox 3.6.10 on Ubuntu 10.4 (Lucid).

---

**Edit:**  The problem does not seem to occur when logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.  This was a caching issue for non-logged-in users.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this.. I started on page 5 and clicked "next page" a bunch of times and I always get the next page.

edit: reproduced in Chrome Incognito mode as anon user!

Comment: Could you try it when logged out?  For me, it works correctly when and only when I'm logged in.

Comment: @joey ah indeed that's the trick -- caching failure. I can repro in Chrome Incognito mode